# NoMethodError: undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class in rails after updating to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

After I updated to ubuntu 12.10, I started getting this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `init' for Mysql:Class

I am using the mysql adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> % gem install mysql

solved the problem. Note that this gem was installed already even before I updated the ubuntu version but somehow the setup got messed up in the update.